# UIAlertController Cancel action background color

Tags: ios, swift3

```
My question is similar to this where I couldn't find the answer.
```

[UIAlertController change background color of Cancel button for action sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601692/uialertcontroller-change-background-color-of-cancel-button-for-action-sheet)
and this [alertController with white borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44719277/alertcontroller-with-white-borders)
I want the cancel button with actionStyle as "Cancel" and the background should be of different colour(By default it will be white). How to change the background colour of Cancel button. I don't want to change the actionStyle to default. Is there any other way to achieve this?
This is my code

```
   func showActionSheet(_ changeAction: UIAlertAction) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Are you sure".localize(), preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor.green
    if let subview = alertController.view.subviews.first, let alertContentView = subview.subviews.first {
        for innerView in alertContentView.subviews {
            innerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel".localize(), style: .cancel) { _ in
        self.doneButton.isEnabled = true
    }
    alertController.addAction(changeAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: you want to change the "Cancel" action font color ?

Comment: In one of the question answer there is a hack, but i would prefer to create my custom alert. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44721186/1031944

Comment: I want the background color of Cancel action to be changed. Not the font or text(Cancel). @SamarthKejriwal

Comment: @Hamdullahshah There is the change in the color of Cancel(text). I want the background to be changed from white color

Comment: You will have to create a custom alert view ,because changing the background color for the action button is not supported in the xcode library

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal Do you have any reference link for that? If please provide them

Comment: @vinny Please refer these . : https://github.com/JSSAlertView/JSSAlertView

https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift

https://github.com/codestergit/SweetAlert-iOS

Comment: You can check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53424527/1919303

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to change it using UIAppearance and a little hack.
See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49066544/3328810)